# How to specify casing for const-reference parameter with clang-tidy?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

`a.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

void func(const int& a, const int b, int c) {
    std::cout << a + b + c << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    func(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to specify casing for parameters `a` and `b`, but not `c` with clang-tidy. How to do this?

I've also opened an issue on the llvm project https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/64220 but maybe someone here has a quick fix.

relevant: https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability/identifier-naming.html

```
clang-tidy -checks='readability-identifier-naming' -config="{CheckOptions: [ {key: readability-identifier-naming.ParameterCase, value: UPPER_CASE} ]}" a.cpp -- -std=c++17
```

catches all parameters.

```
clang-tidy -checks='readability-identifier-naming' -config="{CheckOptions: [ {key: readability-identifier-naming.ConstantParameterCase, value: UPPER_CASE} ]}" a.cpp -- -std=c++17
```

catches only parameter `b`, not `a`. I want to catch both `a`, `b`.

```
clang-tidy --version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 15.0.7
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: skylake
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the request, you want a configuration for the `clang-tidy` check called [readability-identifier-naming](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability/identifier-naming.html) that will require the use of uppercase letters for parameters of type `const int &` and `const int` but not `int`.

In the current release of Clang+LLVM, 16.0.6, this is not possible.  The `ParameterCase` option applies to all three, while the `ConstantParameterCase` option only applies to `const int`, not `const int &`, since the latter is a reference *to* a `const`-qualified type, but is not `const`-qualified itself (reference types cannot be `const`-qualified).

There is no more specific option that applies to a `const int &` parameter than `ParameterCase`, as can be seen from the source code of [`IdentifierNamingCheck::findStyleKind`](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/llvmorg-16.0.6/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/readability/IdentifierNamingCheck.cpp#L1170), excerpted below:

- Parameters are always [`ParmVarDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ParmVarDecl.html) AST objects.
- It (`const int &`) is neither `constexpr` nor `const`.
- It is not a parameter pack.
- It is not [`Type`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Type.html)`::isAnyPointerType()`, as that is true of
  C/C++ pointers and Objective-C pointers, but not references.
- Thus only remaining applicable style is simply `SK_Parameter`,
  which corresponds to the `ParameterCase` option (for letter case
  rules).

This could of course change in a future version if your [Issue #64220](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/64220) is acted upon.  You might want to clarify in that issue that you (now) understand it is not possible in the current version, and you are making an enhancement request.

Source code excerpt:

```
StyleKind IdentifierNamingCheck::findStyleKind(
    const NamedDecl *D,
    ArrayRef<std::optional<IdentifierNamingCheck::NamingStyle>> NamingStyles,
    bool IgnoreMainLikeFunctions) const {
...
 if (const auto *Decl = dyn_cast<ParmVarDecl>(D)) {
    if (isParamInMainLikeFunction(*Decl, IgnoreMainLikeFunctions))
      return SK_Invalid;
    QualType Type = Decl->getType();

    if (Decl->isConstexpr() && NamingStyles[SK_ConstexprVariable])
      return SK_ConstexprVariable;

    if (!Type.isNull() && Type.isConstQualified()) {
      if (Type.getTypePtr()->isAnyPointerType() &&
          NamingStyles[SK_ConstantPointerParameter])
        return SK_ConstantPointerParameter;

      if (NamingStyles[SK_ConstantParameter])
        return SK_ConstantParameter;

      if (NamingStyles[SK_Constant])
        return SK_Constant;
    }

    if (Decl->isParameterPack() && NamingStyles[SK_ParameterPack])
      return SK_ParameterPack;

    if (!Type.isNull() && Type.getTypePtr()->isAnyPointerType() &&
        NamingStyles[SK_PointerParameter])
      return SK_PointerParameter;

    if (NamingStyles[SK_Parameter])
      return SK_Parameter;

    return SK_Invalid;
  }
...
```